# Lifebar : How to increase lifebar oncollision with other object?

Tags: lua, coronasdk

I've build my own lifebar (progressive bar) as follow :

```
function scene:enterScene(event)
    storyboard.removeScene("start")
    screenGroup = self.view 
    lifeBar = {}
    lives = 141 -- is the global width of my full lifebar
    maxLives = 141
    for i = 1, maxLives do
        lifeBar[i] = display.newImage("lifebar.png") --lifebar.png image width is : 1px
        lifeBar[i].anchorX=0
        lifeBar[i].anchorY=0.6
        lifeBar[i].x = fuel_title.x +114+13.5+(lifeBar[i].contentWidth * (i - 1))
        lifeBar[i].y = 37 -- start at 10,10
        lifeBar[i].isVisible=true
        screenGroup:insert(lifeBar[i])
    end
end
```

So, thanks to you, i've know a function which increase the lives (livesValue.text shows the increased lives), whatever, the lifebar{} table seems to have some problems because i cannot see a difference in the lifebar image. My question is : Is there something wrong with my table lifeBar ?

```
 if (event.other.myName == "fuel") then
    if lives > maxLives then
        lives = maxLives
    elseif lives < #lifeBar then
        lives = lives + 1
            lifeBar[lives].isVisible=true
        end
  livesValue.text = string.format("%d", lives)                      
  local other = event.other
  timer.performWithDelay(1, function() other:removeSelf() end)
end
    Runtime:addEventListener("touch", FuelManage)
```

Comment: What is the exact question here? How to add the life? How to handle that collision? Something else?

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
function onCollision( self, event )
    if event.phase == "began" then
        if event.other.myName == "fuel" then

            -- increase life bar, if slots left:
            if lives < #lifeBar then
                lives = lives + 1
                lifeBar[lives].isVisible=true
            end

            -- schedule the fuel object we collided with for removal:
            local other = event.other -- don't want to use event as upvalue
            timer.performWithDelay(1, function() other:removeSelf() end)
        end
    end
end
```

Note that you are not allowed to remove collision objects in the collision handler, you have to do this with delay, as explained on the Corona Collision docs page. So I have done that. Also you should only add lives if you there is space in the lifeBar (similarly you should fix your code to remove life only if there is more than 0 lives).